# TFF : TypeError while saving model

Tags: tensorflow-federated

Please I need Help!
After writing my code of TFF, I would like to save my model So I add this line in the end of code

```
ckpt_manager = checkpoint_manager.FileCheckpointManager("model.h5")
ckpt_manager.save_checkpoint(state, round_num=1)
```

The error was:

```
TypeError: To be compatible with tf.contrib.eager.defun, Python functions must return zero or more Tensors; in compilation of <function FileCheckpointManager.save_checkpoint.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f06b40de730>, found return value of type <class 'tensorflow_federated.python.common_libs.anonymous_tuple.AnonymousTuple'>, which is not a Tensor.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FileCheckpointManager` uses pure TensorFlow API under the hood, and hence doesn't understand TFF's `AnonymousTuple` type used for structured data.

It will be necessary to convert the AnonymousTuple back into the Python structure it was created from. This can sometimes be done via the [`_asdict()` method](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/74fe6f208c68463ebc7f0de265709f10702e4f3d/tensorflow_federated/python/research/gans/gan_training_tf_fns.py#L97) on the `AnonymousTuple`, but that will fail if the tuple has any unnamed fields. Otherwise, performing something like [`from_tff_result` method here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/162e060811afe7551d5562135ade3622edcef8a9/tensorflow_federated/python/research/optimization/shared/fed_avg_schedule.py#L77) will be necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much I modified my code like below: `ckpt_manager.save_checkpoint(fed_avg_schedule.ServerState.from_tff_result(state), round_num=1)`  but I find this error:    `ckpt_manager.save_checkpoint(fed_avg_schedule.ServerState.from_tff_result(state), round_num=1)
  
AttributeError: The tuple of length 4 does not have named field "round_num". Fields (up to first 10): ['model', 'optimizer_state', 'delta_aggregate_state', 'model_broadcast_state']`

Comment: One this line https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/162e060811afe7551d5562135ade3622edcef8a9/tensorflow_federated/python/research/optimization/shared/fed_avg_schedule.py#L87 the checkpoint manager expects `round_num` to get an attribute on `state`, not an additional argument.